# C++ class empty class size 1 byte

Tags: c++, sizeof

I am new to C++ and a found a peculiar feature in C++. I saw the size of an empty is 1 byte, I did some research and found out that is is done because every object must have a distinct address. But I want to know what is the content of that 1 byte that is placed. I know it does not hold the "this" pointer but is it a dummy byte or is there actually some content???

Answer (score 11):

There's no content. It's just a dummy byte.

Every `class` or `struct` must have its `sizeof` greater than `0`, ergo your behavior. It's expected and mandated by the standard.

Comment: Actually in g++ it is possible to define a class having 0 size. See my answer.

Answer (score 10):

It is mandated by the Standard that different objects of the same type should have different addresses. This in turn ensure that for any object `T`, `T*` acts as a unambiguous identifier of this object (for this type).

Granted, you don't often need to know if two objects really are the same or not, but sometimes (given C++ low-level access) this is either necessary or just plain convenient.

It is thus specified that no object should have a null size.

There is an exception to this rule though: when using an empty class as a base class, the compiler may choose to apply the *Empty Base Optimization* (**EBO**) is some circumstances, for example:

```
struct Empty {};

struct Slim: Empty {
  int a;
};

static_assert(sizeof(Slim) == sizeof(int), "");
```

In general the size of the base class is added, but in this particular case it is not necessary. However the rule that two different objects of the same type should never have the same address still apply, and so:

```
struct Fat: Empty {
  Empty e;
};

static_assert(sizeof(Fat) > sizeof(Empty), "");
```

**EBO** is the main reason for using `private` inheritance in template situations. For example:

```
template <typename Allocator>
class MyClass: private Allocator {
};
```

This way, if it turns out that `Allocator` is an empty class, there won't be any overhead. In general, it is thus often used for *policies*, for example the predicates you pass to `map`.

Answer (score 3):

The byte contains nothing, it is there to make certain other behaviors nicer.
For example consider the case of empty classes contained in another.

```
class Empty
{ };

class TwoEmpties
{
  Empty a;
  Empty b;
};
```

You may want the addresses of the two members, `&TwoEmpties::a` and `&TwoEmpties::b`, to be different. For this to happen they must have size > 1. (or the compiler would have to add padding between them, which would in turn complicate the rules for when and where the compiler can add padding to classes.)

Comment: Admittedly you do **not** often want the address of the two members. Indeed, in the majority of cases, you do not **care** about the addresses of the two members. This rule caters to a minority of use cases, though they were judged important enough to mandate it.

Comment: @MatthieuM. agreed. Fixed the wording slightly

Answer (score 2):

You can use your debugger or something simple like `printf("%x", *(unsigned char *)&myobj);` to see the contents of the byte.  I haven't read the C++ specification but I would **guess** that the contents of the byte are undefined so the behavior depends on the compiler and your OS.

Answer (score 1):

An `empty class has a sizeof 1` because when objects of that class are created they will be stored on the same location in memory if size=0.

Suppose that when you create an object the `address is 1000`.

If size of the `class is 0` hence the size of the `object must be 0` as well.

```
(therefore, object is located at 1000+0=1000)
```

So now if another object is made,

```
Add. of 2nd object=1000+0th location
```

Both the objects have same address and this is undefined behavior and shouldn't occur as there will be ambiguity to which object is being referred to.

Hence `empty classes are given a byte of memory` to prevent such situations from happening.

Answer (score 0):

That's a dummy byte - constructor and destructor will be trivial, there's no "data stored".

Answer (score 0):

I faced to similar problem and it seems that one can define a class with zero length with a little trick. I do not know if it is just because of g++, but see the following code snippet:

```
struct ONE {};
struct ZERO { char x[0]; };

int main() {
  cout << sizeof(ONE) << ", " << sizeof(ZERO) << endl;

  ONE* po1 = new ONE;
  ONE* po2 = new ONE;
  cout << po1 << ", " << po2 << endl;

  ZERO* pz1 = new ZERO;
  ZERO* pz2 = new ZERO;
  cout << pz1 << ", " << pz2 << endl;
}
```

The output is:

```
1, 0
0xe4f010, 0xe4f030
0xe4f050, 0xe4f070
```

So the size of an empty class is one (according to the C++ standard), but if it has just a zero length array field the size become zero. If a new really zero sized class is allocated on the heap with `new` a valid address is returned and if allocated multiple times their pointers are pointing to different memory addresses.

Comment: Well, a statically zero-length array is ill-formed.

Comment: @Deduplicator Maybe you are right, but I have seen such structs (having char[0] as a last item) several times. So it is spread somehow.

Comment: struct {
    int length;
    char d[0];
};

Is the variable record length *trick* (although I dislike calling anything so powerful a 'trick' :) ).

Comment: struct {
      int length;å
      char d[0];
   };
Is the variable record length *trick* (although I dislike calling anything so powerful a 'trick' :) ).

As a side-note:  I use the empty structures with std::is_pod<type>() in an inheritance chain.  Adding an empty member (char d[0]) violates the is-pod test for classes inheriting the empty class.

For Example:
struct A {
    static void fn();
};

struct B : A {
     int b;
};

struct B will pass std::is_pod<struct B>() as long as there are no members defined in struct A.

Answer (score -1):

All the above answer is not right as per my knowledge .
The correct answer is by default 4 inbuilt functions are called when object of class is created that is

1. Default constructor
2. Default destructor
3. Copy constructor
4. overloaded assignments operator

hence the size of empty class is 1byte ,
Example : try this

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Test
{
};
int main()
{
Test t;
cout<< "size of empty class is "<<sizeof(t);
}
```